# Can't get rid of source map error in create react app

Tags: reactjs, source-maps

I just created an app using Create React App and I'm getting this error:

```
Source map error: TypeError: Invalid URL: .
Resource URL: blob:http://localhost:3000/49727e77-80fd-4d12-b725-ebdb912769c4
Source Map URL: (really long url)
```

I haven't even started doing anything yet I can't figure out how to get rid of the error.

Comment: Did you try deleting node_modules and doing a yarn install?

Comment: Just tried that and nothing happened. It appears this only happens in firefox so it's probably a problem with the browser

Comment: Yeah that's weird.. not seeing that issue on this end, think this is specific to something local. Maybe a browser plugin. Try disabling all your browser extensions. Source maps are only used in dev anyway so wouldn't be too concerned.